# How to query this dataset to remove entries

Tags: sql, plsql

Does anyone know how to remove entries where column 'BC' equals B1 and where column 'NI' matches i.e. in the below output B1 exists and column 'NI' matches for 3 entries so they should all be removed.

```
select mbd.mf, mml.ef, ni, mcb.bc
from m_mc_lg mml
inner join mem_b_det mbd
on mml.mf=mbd.mf
and mml.cf=mbd.cf
inner join mem_e me
on me.mf=mml.mf
and me.cf=mml.cf 
and me.ef=mml.ef
join mem_care_ben mcb
on mcb.mf=mbd.mf
and mcb.cf=mbd.cf 
and mcb.ef=mml.ef
```

| MF | EF | NI | BC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8047002 | 1 | AA123456A | A1 |
| 7045684 | 1 | BB123456B | B1 |
| 7045684 | 1 | BB123456B | B2 |
| 7045684 | 1 | BB123456B | B3 |
| 6082495 | 1 | CC123456C | C1 |

Answer (score 1):

Try Some thing like this,

```
DELETE FROM m_mc_lg 
WHERE ni IN (SELECT ni FROM m_mc_lg WHERE BC = 'B1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this query:

```
DELETE FROM m_mc_lg 
WHERE BC='B1' 
       OR 
      NI LIKE '%B1%'; -- or 'BB1%'
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only "remove" this entries from your query result, not from your table, you could try this:

```
SELECT
  mbd.mf, mml.ef, ni, mcb.bc
FROM
  m_mc_lg mml
  INNER JOIN mem_b_det mbd ON mml.mf = mbd.mf AND mml.cf = mbd.cf
  INNER JOIN mem_e me ON me.mf = mml.mf AND me.cf = mml.cf AND me.ef = mml.ef
  JOIN mem_care_ben mcb ON mcb.mf = mbd.mf AND mcb.cf = mbd.cf AND mcb.ef = mml.ef
WHERE mcb.bc <> 'B1'
AND NI !~ 'B1'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/MSiDm1TF